# Script to clean up hacked web site

Tags: php, javascript, security, iframe

I'm looking for something like a php script to run on my web-site to clean up corrupted files.

I've found 3 different formats of corruption: 
php files : have an iframe line just before a  
.js files : have a iframe line on the first line of each file
each folder have a default.php file which contains only a line with `echo(decodeBase64(...))`

So, I know how to find/erase the malwares, 
I could then write a script which read/write the files on my server to clean it up.

But It would take hours... So is there already something like that that exists?

(ps: Were hosted on GoDaddy and are not thinking about mooving because of the low price, 
I'm also not a pro about security, even though I know we'll need to patch these security breach, I need some temporary solution for right now)

Comment: Do you have backups? That's the only way you can be sure that the miscreants didn't install additional files that will let them back in again.

Comment: See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314002/how-to-cope-with-help-ive-been-hacked-questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It shouldn't take hours, I wrote a very very very simple script in minutes that you can manually tweak to suit your needs.

Here it is:

```
    $realPath = realpath('path/to/your/wp/installation');
    // The needle is the string that you want to look for in your files
    // gzinflate is pretty common, also try to look for preg_replace or eval,
    // but those instructions are commonly used in WP, so you'll have a bunch of
    // false positives.
    //
    // As far as js files, you might want to also look for document.writes because
    // that's how worms insert iframes into your websites.  
    $needle = "/gzinflate/"; 
    $di = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator( $realPath );
    foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($di) as $filename => $file) {
            $haystack = file_get_contents($filename);
            if(preg_match_all($needle, $haystack, $matches)) {
                   // Outputs suspicious file, not necessarily infected.
                    echo $filename;
                    echo "\n";
            }
```

Comment: `grep -r gzinflate /path/to/your/wp/installation`.

Comment: @Gumbo that only works if OP has ssh access to the web server, since he mentioned the words GoDaddy and Cheap (lol) it's highly unlikely that he has, therefore grep is not an option.

Answer (score 2):

I see you mentioned that you know how to find the malware, but this is important enough that I wanted to call attention to it.

The malicious code got to your site through some means that the attacker used to get access.  It *could* be malware, but it could also be any number of other security issues.  Removing the code will do you no good if you don't also fix your other security problems.  Here are some common things to check:

1. Telnet/FTP and other cleartext protocols are disabled
2. SSH/SFTP is enabled only if needed
3. User accounts (especially those with SSH privileges) have strong passwords
4. Your PHP server is up to date with patches
5. you aren't running any unnecessary services, and the services you are running are up to date on their patches
6. Turn on logging on both your server and your firewall (you do have a firewall, right?), and review existing logs to see if you can find hints about the attack

You may want to scan your server with [Wapiti](http://wapiti.sourceforge.net/) or [W3af](http://w3af.org/) as well to identify common vulnerabilities (like SQL injection) that attackers could be using to compromise your app.

Then use AlanChavez's suggestion to clean up the infected code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, 
I'll check all that but I was looking for a script to run often (once a day) to remove injected code / files... (That way google's scan won't see us as malware)

Comment: @LudovicMigneault You're welcome. Generally speaking if you pass scans from Wapiti or W3af, then chances are good that you will pass Google's scan as well.  Hope that helps

Comment: Removing the immediate symptom once a day but leaving your still-infected server on the net to attack others is deeply irresponsible. To add to Ben's list, ensure all machines that have accessed the server are clean with multiple malware scanners and up to date with OS and application patches, and then change account passwords. The most common source of this kind of infection at the moment is web exploits compromising the client and stealing passwords from it.

Comment: Oops, I forgot to follow that post for a while! Just came back to say that in the end, I got a php script which cleans the page every time a user looks at it (before it returns the page to the user). It's horrible, but I'm just now having a "Hacking and security" Class, maybe I'll clean my server in a better way to practice after my course...